# How to edit profile on all Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: support, profile-page, display-names

I have accounts on multiple Stack Exchange-powered sites. I want to change my nickname on all of them.

Is there a way I can do it from one page that would reflect on all of the Stack Exchange sites?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can edit your profile on one account, go to the `accounts` tab of your profile, then scroll to the bottom of the page. You'll see three buttons – you can click the first one (`Copy X profile to all Stack Exchange accounts`) to then push the changes to all your accounts.

[image]
[image]

Comment: The buttons are not there anymore

Answer (score 39):

This changed recently. There's a tab at the top of your profile:

> [image: tab]

This links to https://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/current.

To save to all the sites, click the "Save and copy changes to all Stack Exchange communities" button at the bottom:

> [image]

Comment: The big difference here is that you have to edit-save-and-push from one of the community sites, *not* from the primary "network account" SE site.  The central account lets you copy your profile info *from* any public community site, but it doesn't push it back out when you do that.  So, do any editing and changing from your favorite community site, and then push from there instead of trying to manage it centrally!

Comment: It's now even easier -- changing your profile for all networks is now the default!

Comment: That link: https://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/current is bookmarked, is exactly what I needed to propagate changes all over the network. Just curious, is there another way to get to that link by navigating a subsite of stackexchange?