# Are there any updates on the project to make the profile page responsive?

Tags: discussion, design, profile-page

In December 2018, there was some [information gathering](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/319375/294691) about what could be improved in the profile pages and settings; the page needed to be adjusted to fit the responsive design in any case, so it made sense to see if other changes needed to made at the same time.

In [March 2019](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/381508/4946380) there was an update posted to Meta.SO. It detailed some of the information gathered, and mentioned some disconnects between how different groups of users used the profile pages and settings.

However, over two years after the initial post and quite a while after the responsive design was rolled out... that page still hasn't been made responsive:

[image: screenshot of unresponsive profile page]

(Note the white spot at the top right, which has been there since day one of the responsive design.)

Are there any updates on this project? Will we be seeing any updates on this besides the information gathering?

Comment: If it's not in the roadmap, it isn't planned so I'm really not optimistic about it. More likely there will be answer like "Sorry this isn't in our roadmap for 2021 so we're aborting this" on the existing posts. And as usual, I can only hope to be wrong...

Comment: Interesting enough I never see that white square

Comment: @Luuklag - do you by any chance have the sidebar expanded on the right?

Comment: I do, @Mithical

Comment: @Luuklag - I'm guessing that's why you don't see it. I keep the sidebar closed, and that's why I see it.

Comment: Worth mentioning that this is now on the roadmap: See [Deprecating our mobile views](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/367609)